# mixing RAM sizes in SuperMicro X10DRH-iT

Tags: memory, supermicro

I have maxed out my server with 16 x 32 GB DIMMs:

32GB PC4-17000 DDR4-2133Mhz 4Rx4 1.2v ECC

I would like to replace 8 of those with larger (64 GB) DIMMS with the *exact same specs*, except 64 GB instead of 32 GB.

The party line is "don't mix sizes" but I wonder, is anyone running mixed-size DIMMs with same specs on this (or other SuperMicro) motherboards and having no issues with it?

Comment: I would refer to your motherboard manual. I mixed RAM in the past, but I had to follow the manufacturer spec for populating the correct bank correctly.

Comment: They advise not to mix in the same bank which I have been further advised means the entire system. It just seems like this is something that *should* work but nobody wants to put their reputation behind it.

Comment: In the same bank mean if dual channel it’s two DIMM that compose the bank, or triple. Its normal you cant mix the bank, but usually you have multiple banks, which can be mixed